# How to set headers on reverse proxy to pass over http on custom port but show https and port 443

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am using NGINX as a reverse proxy to connect to an application hosted in Windows Server.
The connection path for the upstream traffic would be something like:

- Browser to reverse proxy over https on port 443
- Reverse proxy to Windows app server over http on ip 10.1.0.10, port 8080

The relevant configuration in nginx is as follows:

```
server {
    server_name example.com;
    listen 443 ssl http2;

    location / {
        return 301 https://$host/app;
    }

    location ~ ^/app {
        add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN always;
        add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block" always;
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains;" always;
        add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff always;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Connection "";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

        proxy_intercept_errors on;

        proxy_pass http://10.1.0.10:8080;
    }
}
```

I can see that requests to https://example.com/app are initially reaching the server. Problem is, subsequent requests are trying to reach URL http://example.com:8080/app.

It looks like proxy_set_header Host is working as expected (i.e. replacing ip address 10.1.0.10 with example.com), but the protocol and port number are not changing.

I tried adding the following directives:

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host  $host;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port  $server_port;
```

but no luck.

How can NGINX be configured to pass incoming traffic to http://10.1.0.10:8080 while using https://example.com (port 443) in the headers?

Comment: It sounds like your backend is redirecting the client with full URLs  - you may need to remove the port from the `Location` header using regular expressions though I agree NGINX should do this automatically.

Comment: Yes. The issue was not the NGINX configuration, it was the backend indeed!